# Case on a set ignores equality/inequality

Tags: haskell

Pattern-matching is based on `Eq` instance, right? I see that `Data.Set.Set` implements `Eq` and

```hs
>S.fromList [] == S.fromList [1,2]
False
>S.fromList [1,2] == S.fromList [2,1]
True
```

which is right. Then why does

```hs
case S.fromList [1,2] of mempty -> True
```

return true? (actually it always evaluates to true). I mean such matching is wrong and we should use `S.null` as a predicate, but anyway: how does it work and comes to `True`?

Comment: `mempty` is just a variable, so it matches anything.

Comment: FWIW, pattern matching is a primitive operation in Haskell. `(==)` is something defined by a library. (Though it's true a few language constructs will desugars to uses of it, so it's a bit more privileged than most library definitions.)

Comment: It's possible to pattern match on an empty `Set` using an (explicitly-bidirectional) pattern synonym: `pattern Empty :: Set a; pattern Empty <- (null -> True) where Empty = empty`.

Comment: "Pattern-matching is based on `Eq` instance" -- actually, the dependency goes exactly the other way. Any `Eq` instances written for you by the compiler are based on pattern-matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Pattern-matching is based on `Eq` instance, right?

Wrong. In general<sup>†</sup>, pattern matching doesn't have anything to do with `==`. Pattern matching is *structural deconstruction*. This requires having constructors available. `Set` is [internally defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.7/docs/Data-Set-Internal.html) as

```
data Set a    = Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Size !a !(Set a) !(Set a)
              | Tip
```

so you could write

```
import Data.Set.Internal (Set(..))

case S.fromList [1,2] of Tip -> True
```

Notice that the LHS of the pattern is uppercase. This means `Tip` can't be a variable, so the thing you've experiences where it shadows the existing name `mempty` can't happen.

But you're not supposed to do that. `Data.Set` does not export the constructors; the implementation is considered too complicated / unstable to be sensible to access for users. Instead you can just do

```
    if S.null (S.fromList [1,2]) then True
                                 else FLEBLEBLEARG
```

Arguably, at least for the empty case it *would* make sense to have the constructor available. You can actually define a usable version of it yourself with `-XPatternSynonyms` and  `-XViewPatterns`.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>The exception are number literals. To match on such a literal, you need to have instances of both `Num` and `Eq`, and the pattern match works by first converting the literal to the suitable type and then performing an equality check. Likewise for string literals when `-XOverloadedStrings` is enabled.</sub>

Comment: I object to the characterization of `Set` as complicated or unstable. The reason it's abstract is because the data definition has more structure than the interface wishes to expose.

Comment: @Carl which is just a different way of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
case S.fromList [1,2] of mempty -> True
```

is equivalent to

```
case S.fromList [1,2] of wow -> True
```

i.e., it introduces a new local variable named `mempty` or `wow`, which is completely unrelated to the `Monoid` class method with the same name.

The code is very similar to:

```
f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f mempty = mempty ++ mempty
```

where the `mempty` name is, again, a local variable name, unrelated to monoids.

Another more subtle case:

```
isEqual :: Int -> Int -> Bool
isEqual x y = case x of y -> True ; _ -> False
```

This always returns true. The second `y` is unrelated to the first one.

If you keep warnings on with `-Wall`, which I strongly recommend, GHC warns about the dangerous shadowing of names defined in the outer scope.

Answer (score 2):

Identifiers that start with lowercase are *variables*. It thus does *not* check equality with `mempy`, `mempty` is here a pattern that will match anything, and thus create a locally scoped variable `mempty` that you then can use in the "body" of the clause.

This is thus equivalent to:

```
case S.fromList [1,2] of
  avariable -> True
```